# Заменить %-string на f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, print

Как правильно написать выражение

`"%(a)03d%(b)029d" % {"a": 1, "b": 2}`,

используя [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [3]: a,b = 1,2

In [4]: print(f"{a:03d}{b:029d}")
00100000000000000000000000000002
```

или

```
In [5]: d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

In [6]: print(f"{d['a']:03d}{d['b']:029d}")
00100000000000000000000000000002
```

---

Пример использования переменных для задания *формата*:

```
In [9]: fmt1,fmt2 = "03d", "029d"

In [10]: print(f"{d['a']:{fmt1}}{d['b']:{fmt2}}")
00100000000000000000000000000002
```

Comment: А если я хочу использовать переменные, вместо "03d" и "029d" ?

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, дополнил ответ...